# Why are the Final Five accepted by the robotic Cylons?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

The robotic Cylons are created by Colonial humans. The Cylons revolted and are at war with the humans, trying to exterminate them.

For some reason they try to create "skin jobs" (biological Cylons) that look exactly like their enemies (as infiltrators? I can't imagine that they want to create them to be ruled by them.)

Then the Final Five appear. They are biologic life forms (albeit their origin is artificial). They claim for themselves to be "Cylons" (whatever this may mean) and tell the robotic Cylons (who never can have heard of them) that they can help them to create their "skin jobs" if they stop the war. They look exactly like their human enemies that they are trying to exterminate and must be indistinguishable from humans for the them.

Why did the robotic Cylons accept the final five as Cylons?

Comment: youve got a few seperate distinct questions here.

Comment: the short of it is, when the robotic cylons meet the final 5, the 5 offer them the means to create biological life. the robotic cylons want to "evolve" and they view biological life as the next step for themselves. the leobans seem to be the ones that essentially enslave the robotic cylons, and force them to obey.

Comment: @Himarm I agree. But I strongly assume that the answer of the second question is strongly coupled with the answer of the main (first) question and therefore one answers both. The third one I also expect to be answered in this context. Until now I did not found a suitable format to ask strongly related questions separate, without loosing the context and without risking to be marked as duplicates.

Comment: @Himam I can not follow the logic why a robotic lifeform created by humans, at war with its creators, view as a next step in their evolution what essentially is represented by its creators. Shouldn't they see themselfes as above humans and above biological life? If they think that biology/human form is their next step, why not just commit suicide and let their human creators (= next step) win? Humans created robots not as next step and not because they see them superior and want to be replaced (or enslaved) by them. Why should robots want to create humans to do exactly that?

Comment: @Hothie The Boomer that was on Caprica with Helo said they reason they wanted to evolve is because their robotic forms lacked the capacity for reproduction, which they viewed as a critical flaw.

Comment: well from the caprica show, the cylons have conciseness due to a human mind getting trapped inside of one. so from that tract making a new human body would be the goal. but Data from startrek had the same goal to become more human, more like his creator. its a very common thread in sci-fi.

Answer (score 2):

#### Caprica SPOILERS

If you don't want to read Caprica (prequel series to Battlestar Galactica) spoilers, this probably isn't the answer for you.  I'll use spoiler tags for the worst of them, but the answer doesn't make much sense without that background.

> The robotic cylons are created by the caprican humans. They revolted and are at war with the humans, trying to exterminate them (I think).

The Cylons are not exactly trying to exterminate humans.

> The original Cylon was a human, Zoe Graystone, who was making a virtual reality copy of herself.  Her biological body died.  While trying to check on her family, she ended up in one of her father's army robots.  As that was the only one that worked as desired, they then copied it.  So she was in *all* the robots.

Zoe had sympathies for a religious minority.  So when it came to war between the majority and the minority, the Cylons were on the minority's side.  A rather unexpected result from the perspective of the government.

Anyway, the point is that Zoe had reason to want to be human again.  She wasn't crazy about being a robot.  And she thought of herself as human.  She was thus primed to believe a narrative that people were made artificially.  She was

> a human in a robot body.

Why not a robot in a human body?

Comment: I roughly knew the "Caprica" story. But this opens up many other questions (Has every robotic cylon the personality of Zoe? Why is this never shown? Why do the cylons try to kill all humans and not only the polytheistic? And still there is the question of why (in the process of killing all humans) they accept 5 humans (that claim to be cylons) as cylons and accept their offer instead of shooting them on sight (as other humans).